# Ionic 3 - App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I'm trying to install my apk on 2 different devices (Galaxy and LG), but both are displaying "App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt.".

First, I was trying to include Google Login in my app, but it was displaying error 10. Following several posts, I had updated some packages and changed some settings. The result is that my app doesn't install anymore.

What I did:

**Step 1:**

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` (JAVA_HOME in my case), and run:

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
```

**Step 2:**

Create `release-signing.properties` file in the platforms/android

```
 keyAlias=alias_name
 keyPassword=password
 storeFile=my-release-key.keystore
 storePassword=password`
```

**Step 3:**

Go to project directory and run:

```
 cordova build android --release -- --keystore=platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password`
```

**Step 4:**

Go back to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` (JAVA_HOME), and run to validate:

```
 jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release.apk alias_name`
```

**Step 5:**

Copy to Samsung S8+ and LG Stylus 2, both displayed "App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt."

What I have tried:

- Set the system environment variables
- Update Android Studio, Android SDK Tools, Cordova, NPM and Node.js versions
- Update `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`
- Downgrade `build.gradle` to 2.3.3 (and wrapper to 3.3), but happened an error during the build
- Change `config.xml` and `package.json`, in order do not contain a ^ or a ~ in the `android` and `cordova-android` version/spec

**Ionic info:**

```
 Ionic:

    ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.2
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

 Cordova:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
    Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
    Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2, cordova-plugin-googleplus 7.0.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.0, cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2, cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2, cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3

 System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    NodeJS            : v8.4.0
    npm               : 6.8.0
    OS                : Windows 10
```

**More information:**

- Android Studio 3.3.1
- ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_131
- platforms\android\app\build.gradle:

  ```
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
  }
  ```
- platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties:

  ```
  distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
  ```

But the result is the same, and even I don't know if my first problem (error 10 at Google sign in) is solved...

**EDIT**

I had tried to run the emulator, `ionic cordova run android -l -c`, but also displayed an error:

```
Runtime Error
Unexpected Identifier
Stack
SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to downgrade Cordova to 7.0.0 and 6.5.0 versions, and android@6.4.0, but the problem still remains the same.

**EDIT 3**

I tried also build:

```
cordova build android --aot --release --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs -- --keystore=platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password
```

But the problem still remains...

Comment: https://drfone.wondershare.com/android-issue/android-app-not-installed.html - does it install on any Android devices? Maybe you have two phones with corrupted Android OS - per this link. i wouldn't start installing unknown fix programs.. Probably malware in that...

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try downgrading the CLI.
This is what I have. Admittedly on a Mac.
No problems with deployment to Android.

For your scenario - the ios-deploy / XCode stuff won't be relevant.

```
cli packages: (/Users/jgf/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.4 
    Node              : v8.9.3
    npm               : 5.6.0 
    OS                : macOS
    Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/jgf/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

This is how I do my Android builds:

- CLI:

  - ionic cordova build android --prod
- Android Studio:

  - Open project folder  i.e. .\platforms\android
  - Build -> Generate Signed APK
  - -> Next Keystore password
  - -> Next
  - -> Finish
- click locate in notification for release apk
- distribute app-release-apk